# Did you see where the dragon went?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

In a fantasy world where dragons exist, you meet an old woman who saw where the dragon, which some time ago attacked a nearby village, went about ten minutes ago. You ask her, **"Did you see where the dragon went** *(the line isn't mine, from a computer game in the same situation)* **?",** can she answer with "It went towards Riften (a city in the south)" even though she doesn't know if the dragon has reached the city yet(it's a long way) and even if it will actually ever reach it? If "It went towards Riften" isn't good, does "It set off to Riften" better?

Comment: "It went towards Riften" means the dragon went in the direction of Riften. It says nothing about whether it arrived there.

Comment: Yes, you can. It might be more idiomatic to say, 'It was heading for Rifton', or (if she had seen it stop to make a decision) 'It set off towards Riften.'

Comment: @OldBrixtonian if I go out of my back door into the garden, I am certainly going towards Gloucester, but I would not say that I am heading there, or setting off towards it.

Comment: @Michael Harvey You're not a gragon.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, **that makes a lot of sense.** But some people told me that I can't say *"Yesterday, I **went to Moscow at 8:20** and hoped to get there by 8:50, but at 8:30 after 10 minutes of driving I decided to go back home."* Why do you think they say that?

Comment: You could say "I **left** for Moscow at 8:20."

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, or "I **set off** for Moscow at 8:20", thank you! But, after all, you said above in the first comment: ***"It went towards Riften" means the dragon went in the direction of Riften. It says nothing about whether it arrived there."*** with which I completely agree. To me your words make sense.

Comment: "I went to somewhere yesterday" is a completed action. You left your starting place and arrived at your ending place. If you didn't get there for some reason, it would be incorrect to say 'I went there'. If you started to eat a chicken, but the first taste told you it was rotten, so that you stopped, you would not say 'Yesterday I ate a chicken'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - no, indeed. I think these fantasy worlds rot peoples' brains.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey 1) but the time of the action 'to go' refers to the start of the trip, that's what I was told. I went to Moscow at 8:20 and arrived there at 8:50. So, logically I can't see why that has to mean arriving there. 2) Weather Vane said above in the first comment: *"It went towards Riften" means the dragon went in the direction of Riften. **It says nothing about whether it arrived there."*** I can undersand his logic and it's close to my thoughts. What do you think about his opinion? Do native speakers interpret that verb differently?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov **It went towards Riften** only specifies the direction she saw the gragon going. It says nothing about if or when it arrived there or even if it ever intended to go all the way there at all. As Michael Harvey says, by going out of his back door he is heading in the direction of Gloucester, but he has no intention of actually going to Gloucester.

Comment: @PeterJennings *"It **went towards** Riften only specifies the direction she saw the gragon going"* OK, I agree. But why does "yesterday I **went to** Moscow at 8:20" necessarily mean I arrived there? Is it because of the difference between 'to' and 'towards'? The grammar book by Raymond Murphy says they mean the same. So, Murphy is mistaken and I should say *"Yesterday, I went **towards** Moscow at 8:20 and hoped to get there by 8:50, but at 8:30 after 10 minutes of driving I decided to go back home."* instead??

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov Exactly! I'm afraid Mr Murphy is wrong. "went to" means you were actually in Moscow at some point, whilst "went towards" only means that for a while you travelled in the direction of Moscow. It says nothing about whether  you actually got there or even if you intended to go all the way. I could also say "I left my house in the direction of Moscow", but Moscow is over 1860 miles away and I have no intention of going there, I'm just starting out in an easterly direction and going 7 miles down the road to Abingdon.

Comment: @PeterJennings - if it's local flavour we are providing -  Friend: Did you go to Bath yesterday? Me: Well, I set out, but the bus was attacked by a mob of ruffians in Keynsham, and the passengers had to fight them off with the axes provided. After that, we went back to Bristol. I cannot truthfully say 'I went to Bath'. I suppose I could say 'I went to Keynsham' even though that was not my intention.

Comment: (1) I am not sure the old woman would say "It went [towards] X" (2) I imagine her "Pointing South" or towards a road & saying "It went that way" when the "target" is not visible (3) When the "target" is visible , eg If the "gragon" saw a Princess in the nearby castle window , said "Aha ! there she is !" & moved in the Direction of the castle, then the old woman may say "It went to that castle ...." , she might even add ".... to get the Princess! Hurry, go save her!" (4) Definitely not "It set off for X" when the "gragon" was already in motion. Use it when "starting off" , not in the middle !

Comment: Old rural people (especially in fantasy worlds) may not have much idea about geography; the planet may not have a magnetic field that makes compass directions meaningful, or even possible.

Comment: I am not sure whether your comment was towards me , @MichaelHarvey , but in my comment , the old woman does not say "South" ( might be she has no idea about geography or there are no magnetic Directions ) , she only "Points" in the Direction the "gragon" went & then says "It went that way" ....

Comment: @Prem - I suppose I was implying that rural folk would very likely say 'it went in the direction of xxx' where 'xxx' was somewhere local familiar to them. Rather than a compass direction. I think if you asked a sample of rural English people to point towards London, you'd get a variety of directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It went towards Riften" is good. It simply describes the dragon's direction of travel (something that the old woman could observe).  It does not imply that the dragon has arrived, nor that it will ever arrive. It does not say anything about the dragon's intentions, desires, hopes or plans.

"It set off to Riften" is worse.  It implies that the dragon *intends* to travel to Riften.  Unless the old woman has been talking to the dragon about its future plans, how could she know what the dragon *intends*?